# In android studio with java How to load web text as string from an activity for Android 6+ devices

Tags: android, string, web, httpclient, httpurlconnection

From an Activity, How can I retrieve code or text from a website and display to the user ? I'm having difficulties programming back to Android, now developing as for Android 6.0 and newer. Getting deprecated about http client etc.. so I need a little of help.

Can you paste me some code example including "imports" in order to when the app load, from an Activity class, and also when a user click a "button1", to retrieve the text displayed from a web say "yahoo.es", and show a message to the user with the text from the web (loaded and parsed to a string) using Toast.

Help much appreciated in advance

Comment: what did you do so far? share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you are way too ambiguous about your question. Correct me if i am wrong, what you basically want is to get data from internet and display them to user. Right.
If Yes, then the best way to do this is to get JSON response and parse it to display the relevant information onto the screen.

Take for example, you want an App displaying current Weather status of a city.Then to get the Weather data from Internet you need to connect to those websites which provide you that data.

Now one such website is OpenWeatherMap.org. You can use its APIs to retrieve data in JSON format and then display. You need to go through its API documentation.

This is link which will explain you the full process of connecting to an website's API, its retrieval of Data in Json format and ways to render and display them on screen effectively.

https://www.udacity.com/course/android-basics-networking--ud843

Hope it helps.